# Downloading a large dataset in google colaboratory

Tags: colab

I have a link of a dataset, it is  22 gig but in the collab, there is just 32 gig free disk space. The data is in the zip file and after unzipping collab show crash massage. How can I solve this problem? I can't upload it in drive because it is 15 gig.